# Why Does Telnet Succeed If No Route Back To Host That Initiates It

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, telnet, amazon-vpc

Machine A could not make a https connection to Machine B.  I first used telnet to confirm a tcp connection could be made:
telnet MachineB 443

This worked.  So, I concluded that the network between them was set up fine.  It turned out, that I was wrong, and actually Machine A had a route to Machine B, but Machine B did not have a Route back to Machine A.

Why did telnet succeed from A to B if there was no route for B to get back to A?

Comment: Are the two machines in different subnets? Do you have a packet capture from machine B's point of view, or at least do you know (e.g. from webserver logs) what source IP address was seen by machine B?

Comment: Yes, they are in different subnets.  I don't have a packet capture, but I could recreate it with one.  Machine B is supposed to see Machine A's internal IP address as the source.

The setup of this is in AWS.  Machine A is in subnet A in VPC A.  Machine B is in subnet B in VPC B.  Machine A's subnet has a route table entry that can send traffic to Machine B.  Machine B's subnet did not have a route table entry to send traffic to Machine A.  Machine B has a security group that allows Inbound traffic form Machine A's IP.  So, that's why seemingly it sees that source IP.

Comment: Ah, I don't know much about routing in AWS VPCs – I was assuming this is a physical network. Does either the machine B itself or its subnet gateway have _any_ routes matching A's address? Could it be that the packets just got delivered indirectly, through a default AWS gateway?

Comment: No, it had zero routes matching A's address.  If no route is matched, the packets would be sent to a NAT Gateway in a public subnet.  And the NAT gateway only has a route table entry to go over the internet-- so it would not be able to get back to Machine A in internal subnet A.  The AWS video game abstracts away a lot of the networking legos.  On a physical network do you have any hypotheses as to how the above described behavior could happen?

Comment: AFAIK, on a physical network just 3 options are likely: either it wouldn't happen, or it would happen due to a default route or some similar "triangular routing" result, or it would happen due to unexpected SNAT being performed between the subnets [hence the 'source IP address' question]. (I guess I can imagine something weirder, but I doubt anything like that could occur on cloud infra.)

Comment: When you telnet to machineB, does it show that the client address is machineA's address? I suspect there may be a proxy involved.

Comment: I think that the source IP address must be Machine A because otherwise the Security Group on Machine B would reject it (ie- Machine B allows the IP of Machine A).  AWS being involved in the workflow adds obscurity to the question because I don't know what they do behind the scenes.  I will raise a ticket with them and report back here on what they say.

Comment: When things work weirdly, "I think that it must be" isn't good enough – run `netstat -n -t` while connected (or even fire up tcpdump) to find out for sure.